# How to fix issues since upgrading Node version

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

First, I have to confess, my package.json is a mess.

With that off my chest, I've upgraded my version of Node, first to 12.x and then to 14.x but with both I'm getting `primordials is not defined`, in reference to `fs.js` apparently.

Searching tells me this is related to Gulp, but I'm not using Gulp. Next option, that I'm using a module that isn't supported on later version of Node.

The question is, which one? I've run `depcheck` which is showing a *lot* of unused dependencies (I did confess earlier!), but I'm loathed to start pulling them out, as for instance, `ejs` shows a false negative because of the way it is required `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')`

What's my best move? Are there any tools that might assist me here? Any suggestions to how I might get out of this (totally self induced) mess would be greatly received!

EDIT trace from primordial error

```
0|main     | ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
0|main     |     at fs.js:45:5
0|main     |     at req_ (/var/app/node_modules/natives/index.js:143:24)
0|main     |     at Object.req [as require] (/var/app/node_modules/natives/index.js:55:10)
0|main     |     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/node_modules/s3/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:1:37)
0|main     |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
0|main     |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
0|main     |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
0|main     |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
0|main     |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
0|main     |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
```

I've updated both `s3` and `graceful-fs` to the latest versions. `node src/index.js --trace-warnings` still giving:

```
Env: dev
S3: wasabi
fs.js:45
} = primordials;
    ^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:45:5
    at req_ (/var/app/node_modules/natives/index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (/var/app/node_modules/natives/index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/node_modules/s3/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
```

Comment: Please provide a stack trace if possible.

Comment: Done, and in doing so I've just spotted s3 in that trace... is that the offending module? Also cjs but that's internal so I'm not sure what that is?